# javaw.exe process hangs on applet start

Tags: java, windows, applet

Periodically we have this problem that prevents an applet to go running, the process javaw.exe seems locked, killing them several times unlock the applet. In the trace file I find this (we have jdk 1.6_35, the applet is used by a j2ee web application):

```
**server running at port: 50091
basic: unique id: JavaControlPanel
basic: server port at: 49187
basic: getSingleInstanceFilename: C:\Users\amoriconi\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\tmp\si\JavaControlPanel-x86_49187
basic: file should be removed: C:\Users\amoriconi\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\tmp\si\JavaControlPanel-x86_50091
basic: waiting connection
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList.tryGet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.services.WPlatformService.getSecureRandom(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.si.SingleInstanceImpl.getSecureRandom(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.si.SingleInstanceImpl.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.si.SingleInstanceImpl$SingleInstanceServer$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.si.SingleInstanceImpl$SingleInstanceServer.createSingleInstanceFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.si.SingleInstanceImpl$SingleInstanceServer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.si.SingleInstanceImpl.addSingleInstanceListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SecureRandom(provider: SUN)cannot be found.
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE.<clinit>(DashoA13*..)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SecureRandom(provider: SUN)cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/deploy/security/WSecureRandom
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more**
```

For some reason this problem is originated from an hidden update of java, installing jdk 7u45 and then removing solve for some time the problem.....
I'm going crazy....

Comment: Check the Windows Control Panel for the java thing and make sure that's not set to auto update.  It sounds like java is trying to update and failing part way through (possibly because some of the files are in use by the applet).

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because there are more security checks that have been imposed on applets in the new release of the JRE (7u45-b18).

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html#newft

Its good to be on old JRE or implement security related changes.